# JPA caching database results, need to "un-cache"

Tags: mysql, jpa

I'm seeing "caching" behavior with database (MySQL 5) records. I can't seem to see the new data application side w/o logging in/out or restarting the app server (Glassfish 3).  This is the only place in the application where db records are "stuck."  I'm guessing I'm missing something with  JPA persistence.

I've attempted changing db records by hand, there's still some sort of caching mechanism in place "helping" me.

This is `editFile()` method that saves new data.

- After I fire this, I see the data updated in the db as expected.
- `this.file` is the class level property that the view uses to show file data.  It shows old data.  I attempt to move db data back in to it after I've fired my `UPDATE` queries with the `filesList` setter: `this.setFilesList(newFiles);`
- When the application reads it back out though, GlassFish seems to resond with requests for this data w/ old data.

---

```
public void editFile(Map<String, String> params) {
    // update file1 record
    File1 thisFile = new File1();
    thisFile.setFileId(Integer.parseInt(params.get("reload-form:fileID")));
    thisFile.setTitle(params.get("reload-form:input-small-name"));
    thisFile.setTitle_friendly(params.get("reload-form:input-small-title-friendly"));
    this.filesFacade.updateFileRecord(thisFile);

    //update files_to_categories record
    int thisFileKeywordID = Integer.parseInt(params.get("reload-form:select0"));
    this.filesToCategoriesFacade.updateFilesToCategoriesRecords(thisFile.getFileId(), thisFileKeywordID);

    this.file = this.filesFacade.findFileByID(thisFile.getFileId());   
    List<File1> newFiles = (List<File1>)this.filesFacade.findAllByRange(low, high);
    this.setFilesList(newFiles);
}
```

### Facades

My Facades are firing native SQL to update each of those DB tables.  When I check the DB after they fire, the data is going in, that part is happening as I expect and hope.

**File1**

```
public int updateFileRecord(File1 file){
    String title = file.getTitle();
    String title_titleFriendly = file.getTitle_friendly();
    int fileID = file.getFileId();
    int result = 0;      

    Query q = this.em.createNativeQuery("UPDATE file1 set title = ?1, title_friendly = ?2 where file_id = ?3");
    q.setParameter(1, title);
    q.setParameter(2, title_titleFriendly);
    q.setParameter(3, fileID);
    result = q.executeUpdate();
    return result; 
}
```

**FilesToCategories**

```
public int updateFilesToCategoriesRecords(int fileId, int keywordID){
    Query q = this.em.createNativeQuery("UPDATE files_to_categories set categories = ?1 where file1 = ?2");
    q.setParameter(1, keywordID);
    q.setParameter(2, fileId);
    return q.executeUpdate();
}
```

How do I un-cache?

Thanks again for looking.

Comment: You are firing native SQL statements directly to the back-end database. Try the same using respective `EntityManager`'s method such as `EntityManager#merge(entity)`, `EntityManager#persist(entity)` and `EntityManager#remove(entity)`.

Comment: In your editFile-Method you do `File1 thisFile = new File1();
    thisFile.setFileId(Integer.parseInt(params.get("reload-form:fileID")));`, but with JPA you should do: `File1 thisFile = em.find(File1.class, Integer.parseInt(params.get("reload-form:fileID")));` to get the File from JPA with all it's dependencies and predefined Fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@daniel & @Tiny got me going on this one, thanks again guys.

- I wanted to point out that I used the `.merge()` method out of the Entity Manager class.
- It's important to note that for `.merge()` to **UPDATE** the record instead of **INSERT**ing a new one; that the object you're submitting to `.merge()` must include all properties respective of the fields in the database table (that your DAO knows about) or you will **INSERT** new database records.

---

```
public void updateFileRecord(File1 file){
  em.merge(file);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think caching is the Problem, I think it's transactions.

```
em.getTransaction().begin(); 
Query q = this.em.createNativeQuery("UPDATE file1 set title = ?1, title_friendly = ?2 where file_id = ?3");
        q.setParameter(1, title);
        q.setParameter(2, title_titleFriendly);
        q.setParameter(3, fileID);
        result = q.executeUpdate();
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

I recommend to surrond your Writings to the DB with Transactions to get them persisted. Unless you commit requests may return results without the changes.

Ok, JTA does the Transactionmanagement.

Why are you doing this, when you are using JPA.

```
public int updateFileRecord(File1 file){
    String title = file.getTitle();
    String title_titleFriendly = file.getTitle_friendly();
    int fileID = file.getFileId();
    int result = 0;      
    Query q = this.em.createNativeQuery("UPDATE file1 set title = ?1, title_friendly = ?2 where file_id = ?3");
    q.setParameter(1, title);
    q.setParameter(2, title_titleFriendly);
    q.setParameter(3, fileID);
    result = q.executeUpdate();
    return result; 
}
```

This should work and update the internal State that comes with JPA

```
public int updateFileRecord(File1 file){
  em.persist(file);
}
```

Comment: Hi @daniel thanks for your help, I tried wrapping those Facade methods like this (http://goo.gl/Uc7ydK), but am getting a `JTA` error (at the bottom of that gist there).

Comment: Ok, sorry, did not read the whole code, in JAVA the container can also take care of your Transactions. That's called JTA, so you must not do what I recommended. It was just a first guess. But I have another suggestion

Comment: Ahh @daniel, this is good!  I'm roughing this in now.  Did not know about `em.persist()`!

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction with the entity manager, @Tiny, it was `.merge()` thanks guys.